# Video Editing ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

****Overview:****

Making a multimedia website. Primary focus is to click and drag video clips from any computer file to the website instantly. Has to be very simple and user friendly. Editing videos by creating effects, cut/slash video parts, adding animation, fill effects, caption, different fonts of videos, etc. We do not want a software for the user to download, everything has to be done on the website.

Is this possible in asp.net.

Answer (score 2):

asp.net by itself cannot do this.

You will need help from several sources:

- Third party libraries to transform uploaded video from mpg, flash,
  mov to whatever you will use.
- Anti Virus software to scan the files before they can be transformed
- Silverlight to edit video online

But yes, asp.net can support the underline web site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/). It runs on client side and can be hosted in asp.net.

Comment: with HTML 5 there are browsers compatibilities issues :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible as with most things, but I am not sure you realise what a big piece of coding you are talking about. There are a number of online video editors (YouTube being the most famous) but the issues you will face are huge, such as multiple codecs and conversion to and from and bandwidth issues for uploading videos and downloaded edited content.

Have a look at some of the online video editors:

http://savedelete.com/10-best-and-free-online-video-editing-software.html

and then consider how much budget you have to create your tool. You may wish to use a more clientside approach with silverlight or adobe air but still you face a huge amount of coding to do this right. You will also need to draw upon third party and open source libraries for the actual editing of the videos.

Good luck with the project.